# Hadoop -ls command

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I try to understand this hadoop bash command.

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /file/path > log_$(date +"%y-%m-%d")_file.txt
```

I understand that `hdfs dfs -ls -r /file/path` is a simple recursive `ls` command. But what does the `>` do in this bash command?

Elias

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: Or if you have bash installed try :    `PAGER='less +/^redirection' man bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard output redirect to the file. So the command save result of -ls in log_$current_date_file.txt file